# unity c# Why Abort() is called but ThreadState become WaitSleepJoin?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> The first print ~~~~~~~~result is WaitSleepJoin. This method is called in a while(totaltime>0){}

> In other codes it usually become AbortRequested and then Stopped. Why this one different?

```
 private void timerMethod(int time, string timerName){  
  if(timerThread!=null){
   Debug.Log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"+(timerThread.ThreadState));
  }
    
  if(timerThread!=null&&timerThread.ThreadState==System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped){
    timerThread=null;
      } 
  if(timerThread==null){
    timerThread=new Thread(()=>timerContent(time, timerName));
    timerThread.Start();

    } 

} 
private void timerContent(int time, string timerName){
    int totaltime=time;
    while(totaltime>0){
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            totaltime--;
            talkingTimeShowInt=totaltime; 
              }      
     timerThread.Abort();   
}
```

Comment: timerMethod() is not doing anything useful if the thread is still busy.  Other than indicating that it is inside Thread.Sleep() with ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin.  Or triggering the threading race bug in this code, that doesn't happen often enough to notice it while testing the code.  Don't use it.  Google "unity countdown timer" to get ahead.

Comment: You're aborting your own thread right before it stops on its own. Why? And why do you insist on using threads for a timer?

Comment: @HansPassant If I create a instance of a timer Class with realize MonoBehaviour, the 2 Update() are serve to 2 independent threads? Or both of them run in main thread?

Comment: @Luaan When time count is finished, the thread must be shutdown for later useful. If let it self stop, I worry it still running while I call a new thread, that may occupy resources (Let it self stop, the threadState print run about 20000 times). Also use thread as timer can make codes more clean, easy to maintain.

Comment: @heinzQ - Calling `Abort` on a thread is only useful when **forcilby shutting down your entire app**. Otherwise `Abort` can corrupt the run-time and put your other threads into an unknown state. It's not something that you can call if you wish your app to keep running.

Comment: @Enigmativity So how to kill thread safely with app keep running? If I do nothing, it will run until self shutdown, but that usually takes a long time and no one know the exactly time. Code become unstable.

Comment: @heinzQ - The only way to kill a thread safely is to start a new `Process`, run the code there, and then kill the process. You cannot do it safely within the one process without risking the current process. You are better off trying to get the thread to co-operatively end its own life.

Comment: @Enigmativity Or, as the OP is doing, calling `Abort` on the currently running thread. The problems you're talking about "only" happen when you try to abort a different thread (which may be doing all sorts of things at the time, including things like running static constructors).

Comment: @heinzQ My advice would be to stop using manual threads in the first place. They're extremely rarely needed, and always tricky to use and require a lot of knowledge and experience to use right. Just use a timer, that's what they're for. No need to waste threads on _waiting_ . Don't get stuck on approaches that were outdated 20 years ago.

Comment: @Luaan - Why did you put ***only*** in double-quotes? That usually means that you're using the word, even though you know it's not exactly the right word. What did you mean by that?

Comment: @Enigmativity Strictly speaking, there are cases where you can get in trouble even when aborting your own thread - for example, if you abort in the middle of a static constructor. In practice, that's not going to happen if you do good multi-threaded design, and it's no worse than any other exception that can happen. The main problem with aborting other threads is that you're causing an asynchronous exception that can pop up at arbitrary times (as long as you're in managed code etc.) - aborting yourself is no different from throwing an exception.